# want to show generated thumbnails in array of image view till 5 video capture

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmapimage, touchimageview

want to show thumbnails generated after each video capture will be shown on camera preview in an array of particular size.

for example:
1st video taken ->bitmap generated->shown on camera preview.
2nd video taken ->bitmap generated->shown on camera preview.
3rd
4th
5th
and so on......
likewise till a particular size of array(lets say 5) it will go.

How can I achieve it any idea?

this I am using to generate thumbnail of video.

```
                    Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mVideoFileName, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmapView);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```